# URLConnection not retrieving Headers

Tags: java, matlab, soap

I am trying to use a Web Service in Matlab but I have a problem.

The webservice sends a cookie for authentication which matlab ignores.
The matlab function callSoapService uses this java code:

```
url = URL(endpoint);
if isempty(proxy)
    httpConn = url.openConnection;
else
    httpConn = url.openConnection(proxy);
end
httpConn.setRequestProperty('Content-Type','text/xml; charset=utf-8');
httpConn.setRequestProperty('SOAPAction',soapAction);
httpConn.setRequestMethod('POST');
httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
httpConn.setDoInput(true);
outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream;
outputStream.write(b);
outputStream.close;
inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream;
byteArrayOutputStream = java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
isc = InterruptibleStreamCopier.getInterruptibleStreamCopier;
isc.copyStream(inputStream,byteArrayOutputStream);
inputStream.close;
byteArrayOutputStream.close;
resp = byteArrayOutputStream.toString('UTF-8');
```

If I write **httpConn.getHeaderFields()** it returns an empty list, instead of the headers with the cookie. Any idea?
In the java documentation it says you should call httpConn.connect() and Matlab does not do that, I added that line somewhere in the code just to try, but it didnt work lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

ASP.NET was not sending the cookie because the browser capabilities object for the java user agent Mozilla/5.0 (Java 1.6.0_17; Windows 7 6.1 amd64; en_US) ICEbrowser/v6_0_2 returns false in the Cookies field.

I created a new java.browser file and put it in the App_Browsers directory. I redeployed the application and it worked! ASP.Net sends the cookie to Matlab.

What I had to do next is to modify the Matlab Soap function so it would receive and resend the cookie everytime. I posted the solution to that in http://www.cadec-online.com/Help/API.aspx#Matlab

I reported this issue to matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/support/service_requests/Service_Request_Detail.do?row_id=1-GQMEDO

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilities.aspx